# Load mongoose model in mocha test

Tags: inheritance, mongoose, mocha.js, mean-stack, discriminator

I want to create a subclass of the parent class, `Person`. I created an endpoint `Customer`, and everything works great in development. However, in test, `Person` is not being imported at all.

Any ideas how I can make sure Person is imported correctly?

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Person from '../person/person.model';

const Customer = Person.discriminator('Customer',
  new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      things: [String],
    }
  )
);

export default module.exports = Customer;
```